# Python prompt for user with echo and password without echo

Tags: python, python-2.7

Following code prompts for user and password, when run in console:

```
import getpass

user = getpass.getpass("Username:")
passwd = getpass.getpass("Password for " + user + ":")

print "Got", user, passwd
```

The obvious problem with above is, user name is not echoed as it is typed.

Now [`getpass` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) says *"On Unix it defaults to using /dev/tty before falling back to sys.stdin and sys.stderr."*

**Question:** How to ask for both username and password, so that they are read from same source, and username is echoed normally, while password is not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is another alternative, which I found documented [here](https://pymotw.com/2/getpass/).  Detect whether the input stream is a TTY, and change your input method based on that information.

I used something like this:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import getpass

if sys.stdin.isatty():
   print "Enter credentials"
   username = raw_input("Username: ")
   password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
else:
   username = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
   password = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()

print "Username: [%s], password [%s]" % (username, password)
```

This works fine from a terminal:

```
bash> ./mytest.py
Enter credentials
Username: one
Password:
Username: [one], password [two]
```

for piped input:

```
bash> echo "one
> two" | ./mytest.py
Username: [one], password [two]
```

for input from a file:

```
bash> echo "one" > input
bash> echo "two" >> input
bash> ./mytest.py < input
Username: [one], password [two]
```

and also for a heredoc:

```
bash> ./mytest.py << EOF
> one
> two
> EOF
Username: [one], password [two]
```

Personally, that covers all of my needs.

Comment: Short and seems to work. And for python 3 version, replace `raw_input` with `input`, and enclose `print` parameters in parenthesis.

Answer (score 16):

Why not just use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) for the username:

```
import getpass

user = raw_input("Username:")
passwd = getpass.getpass("Password for " + user + ":")

print("Got", user, passwd)
```

Demo:

```
Username:iCodez
Password for iCodez:
('Got', 'iCodez', 'secret')
```

Comment: I think this might not answer the question correctly. As written in the question, the documentation of `getpass` says *"On Unix it defaults to using /dev/tty before falling back to sys.stdin and sys.stderr"*. You will see the difference of `raw_input` and `getpass` when you are executing your program like this on linux: `./my_program.py < input_file.txt`.

Comment: python3: use `input` instead of `raw_input`

Answer (score 12):

In Python 2.x, use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) (`input` in Python 3.x) instead of `getpass.getpass` for username.

```
user = raw_input("Username:")
```

Answer (score 5):

It would be possible to use `raw_input` (`input` in Python 3) but as already mentioned in the question, `getpass` is using /dev/tty before falling back to sys.stdin and sys.stderr. This means that in some situations `getpass` and `raw_input` is using different sources.

On linux, you might see the difference by executing the application with the following command:

```
my_app.py < /path/to/some/file
```

The function `raw_input` would read from the file while `getpass` would still use the terminal. Even if it is not documented explicitly, the same is happening on Windows.

---

I have not found a function that is doing something like `getpass` without hiding the input. I think you have to implement it yourself or search for a library which is doing it. You can look at the current implementation of `getpass` [in Python 3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/47f0bf1511bfc89de123f284fa93a5dd1374f063/Lib/getpass.py) and [in Python 2.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6da1f1d0a3c9ca326e9c60b70a54df4d5488d26c/Lib/getpass.py) to get some inspiration.

I wrote an exmaple below. Basically, I used the implementation of Python 3 and removed everything that is related to hiding the input. Then, I made some changes to support Python 2.

```
def _raw_input(prompt, fin, fout):
    if prompt:
        try:
            fout.write(prompt)
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            # Replace characters that are not supported by the terminal
            prompt = prompt.encode(fout.encoding, 'replace')
            prompt = prompt.decode(fout.encoding)
            fout.write(prompt)
        fout.flush()

    line = fin.readline()
    return line[:-1] if line[-1] == '\n' else line

def _ttyinput_unix(prompt):
    try:
        fd = os.open("/dev/tty", os.O_RDWR, os.O_NOCTTY)
        if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
            with os.fdopen(fd, 'w+', 1) as tty:
                return _raw_input(prompt, tty, tty)
        with io.FileIO(fd, 'w+') as tty:
            with io.TextIOWrapper(tty) as wrapper:
                return _raw_input(prompt, wrapper, wrapper)
    except (OSError, AttributeError) as e:
        return _raw_input(prompt, sys.stdin, sys.stderr)

def _ttyinput_win(prompt):
    if sys.stdin is not sys.__stdin__:
        # I don't know why getpass is doing this.
        return _raw_input(prompt, sys.stdin, sys.stderr)

    if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
        getch = msvcrt.getwch
        putch = msvcrt.putwch
    else:
        getch = msvcrt.getch
        putch = msvcrt.putch

    for c in prompt:
        putch(c)

    password = ""
    while True:
        c = getch()
        if c == '\r' or c == '\n':
            break
        if c == '\003':
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        if c == '\b':
            if len(password) > 0:
                password = password[:-1]
                for x in "\b \b":
                    putch(x)
        else:
            password += c
            putch(c)
    putch('\r')
    putch('\n')

    return password

try:
    import msvcrt
    ttyinput = _ttyinput_win
except ImportError:
    ttyinput = _ttyinput_unix
```

I tested my implementation with Python 2.7 on Windows and with Python 2.7 and 3.5 on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
user = raw_input("Username:")
```